Is it possible mankind has not yet discovered elements that could be the basis of organisms entirely different from our concept of life?
One "entity" could not be made of carbon? Could it be "imaterial", from our perspection? Could it not be visible, but still be material?

Hi Bruno. Welcome to Astronomy.SE. What about this question is related to Astronomy?

move this to the  physics stax

Pretty certain Physics would reject this one.

I’m voting to close this question because this is not about Astronomy.

This question is similar to: Question about the formation of elements. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Clearly I lack the knowledge to debate about such complex subject. It's pure sci-fi speculation. Sorry for wasting your time. I remembered the so called "Clarke's 3 laws".

No.
All the elements below uranium are known, and transuranic elements become more unstable the heavier they get.
There may be an island of stability in very heavy nuclei, but those  cannot be created naturally. We can't even make them ourselves.
=== Note that this question doesn't have anything to do with astronomy.

Best not to answer questions that are off topic, otherwise we get more like them.

A very minor comment: trace amounts of neptunium and plutonium are also found naturally.

@PeterErwin from Supernova nucleosynthesis?

@RoryAlsop Oops, sorry. Yes.  I just like explaining stuff. Somebody move this to the physics stax it would be appropriate.

@Miss_Understands For plutonium, yes; they’re also (rare) byproducts of decays in uranium ores.

Plutonium is heavier than uranium. How?

Example: U-238 absorbs a neutron (from e.g.spontaneous fission of another nearby U atom) -> U-239 -> Np-239 -> Pu-239.

Jesus, that happens in nature? Wow. She surprises me every day.

Astrobiology, which this question kinda-sorta asks about, is both astronomy and biology. So this question is applicable to this site--but not to physics SE. My "kinda-sorta" is a bit flippant. Asking about lfe as we do not know it is an astronomical topic. Not a particularly good topic, but it does belong here. Or maybe on WorldBuilding.

@DavidHammen This question should never have been answered. It's utterly off-topic, firstly for being purely hypothetical (an undiscovered element), secondly for being purely biological ("organisms entirely different from our concept of life"), and thirdly nonsensical ("Could it not be visible, but still be material?"). There's no "astro" in this question at all.


One "entity" could not be made of carbon?

Yes. There have been, for example, speculations of silicon-based life. There have been even more speculative speculations about even more exotic life forms. These are of course highly speculative.

Could it be "imaterial", from our perspection? Could it not be visible, but still be material?

I'm not going to say no, but... Science fiction has lots of stories about life in various forms, not just life as we do not know it, but life as we really do not know it, and that includes 'immaterial' life. Whatever that is. But that's science fiction.
Real-lfe scientists are mostly looking for signs of life as we know it (which means carbon-based). There are many good reasons for this perspective.
